# fullpage.js vertical align issue

Tags: javascript, html, css, fullpage.js

i cannot get fullpage.js vertically align any content i give. first i tried to implement it on an existing code but afterwards i just opened anew and tried to put it in just as simple as:

```
<body>
    <div id="fullpage">
        <div class="section">
            <div class="first">
                <img src="img/logo.svg" alt="">
            </div>              
        </div>
        <div class="section">b</div>
        <div class="section">c</div>
        <div class="section">d</div>
    </div>
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script> <!-- Jquery -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> <!-- bootstrap js -->
    <script src="js/jquery.fullPage.js"></script> <!-- Jquery  FullPage-->
    <script src="js/main.js"></script> <!-- Site Library -->
</body>
```

my css dependencies are simple : reset.css, bootstrap and animate.css

i appreciate any kind of help, thanks in advance

Comment: put every tags related to height: 100%, `#fullpage,.section,.first,body,html{height:100%}`

Comment: Align how? ... An image showing it would help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this, copy paste to a html page and make sure your `js` and `css` calling path is right

```js
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
 $('#fullpage').fullpage({
  sectionsColor: ['#999', '#666', '#262626', '#000'],
  navigation: true,
  verticalCentered: true,
  navigationPosition: 'right',
  navigationTooltips: ['About', 'Security', 'Industries', ' security', 'footer'],
 });
});


</script>
```

```css
body {
 float: left;
 width: 100%;
 padding-bottom: 0px;
}
* {
 color:#F00;
 text-align:center;
 font-size:30px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.fullPage.css" >

<div id="fullpage">
  <div class="section" id="section0">
     <span class="middle">Vertical align</span>
  </div>
  
  <div class="section" id="section1">
   <span class="middle">b</span>
  </div>
  
  <div class="section" id="section2">
   <span class="middle">c<span>
  </div>
  
  <div class="section" id="section3">
  <span class="middle">d</span>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script src="js/jquery.fullPage.js"></script>
```

Comment: i am working with gulp task to minify all the dependencies, and the order of the concat and minify command was just wrong, your reply gave me the inspiration to find it out, thanks a lot.